# Pagination in material dashboard tabs not working

Tags: angular6

I was working with angular material dashboard . but on the tab's pagination is not working .
i used

```
  <mat-paginator
    [length]="100"
    [pageSize]="3"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,20]"
  ></mat-paginator>
```

[image: site]

Comment: I just want to paginate the result of bugs in the site.

Comment: Pagination is showing but not working